# I want to maintain current date files

Tags: powershell

## Delete all Files in C:\temp older than Current day(s)

$Path = "E:\Testing\Order\123456"

$CurrentDate = Get-Date

Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $CurrentDate } | Remove-Item

I am trying to run this script but it is deleting every thing. It is not maintain current date files. Is there any modification please suggesting me sir.

Comment: Have you got any code so far? Either use filter/exclusion or on Remove-Item or Get-ChildItem in order to not process some files.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you get the file extensions right if they have any.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder1\data -Include * -Exclude text.1, folder1  -Recurse | foreach { $_.Delete()}
```

*Edit to answer the comment:*

So you want to delete all files and folders in C:\folder1 except of files text.1 and folder.1 in data, other and alpha? It means you cannot remove these 3 folders too so they have to be excluded.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\folder1\ -Include * -Exclude text.1, folder.1, alpha, data, other  -Recurse | foreach { $_.FullName}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it is working. and i want to exclude files and folder in three paths.i want this script in single file please help me sir.                                                        example: C:\folder1\data1\text.1
C:\folder1\data1\folder.1

C:\folder1\data2\text.1
C:\folder1\data2\folder.1

C:\folder1\data3\text.1
C:\folder1\data3\folder.1

Comment: @VenkateshReddi I'm not sure what you mean. You can add any number of folders or files after -Exclude. If I answered your original question, please mark my post as an answer or maybe modify your question so I can help more.

Comment: C:\folder1\data\text.1
C:\folder1\data\folder.1

C:\folder1\other\text.1
C:\folder1\other\folder.1

C:\folder1\alpha\text.1
C:\folder1\alpha\folder.1
I want to excude "text.1" and "folder.1" these file in C:\folder1\data and C:\folder1\other and C:\folder1\alpha in these paths.

Comment: I fixed some typos in the files names, try again.

Comment: I am trying to run this script but it is deleting every thing. It is not maintaine current date files. Is there any modification please suggesting me sir.
 
# Delete all Files in C:\temp older than Current day(s)
$Path = "E:\Testing\Order\123456"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -lt $CurrentDate } | Remove-Item

Answer (score 0):

try this (and dont stay into your dir when you try) :

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\folder1\data\*" -Recurse | where Name -notin ('text.1', 'folder.1') | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: Sir i want to run these three scripts in one file and execute one by one please help me.$Path = "E:\Testing\Order\goods"
$exclude = @("*default", "*New folder")
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Recurse

$Path = "E:\Testing\Order\Transport"
$exclude = @("*default", "*New folder")
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Recurse

$Path = "E:\Testing\Order\Vehical"
$exclude = @("*default", "*New folder")
Get-ChildItem $Path -Exclude $exclude | Remove-Item -Recurse